# Creating blur effect with css and jQuery on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, scroll

I am trying to create blur effect when the user scrolls up and down the browser window using css and jquery. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="out">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="this-div-kills-browsers">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.out {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background: url(https://placekitten.com/1200/800) no-repeat;
}
.this-div-kills-browsers {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var hideThatKitty = $('.out').innerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
     hideThatKitty = hideThatKitty/$('.this-div-kills-browsers').offset().top    
    $('.inner').css('background', rgba(255, 255, 255, \''0'+hideThatKitty\'));
});
```

**[demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dmxLnuy/)**

What i am trying to do is increasing and decreasing the alpha value of css rule background:rgba() with jquery when the user scroll up and down, So it will get blurred with scrolling. Or is there another way of doing this? Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Is expected for "blur" effect to be applied to image ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scrolling while bluring an image

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/vduucu87/

**Code**

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var pixs = $(document).scrollTop()
    pixs = pixs / 100;
    $(".out").css({"-webkit-filter": "blur("+pixs+"px)","filter": "blur("+pixs+"px)" })     
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For "blur" effect , try utilizing `css` [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) `blur(Npx)` , where *`N`* is a number; `px` `css` pixel units e.g.; `4px`

```js
var hideThatKitty = $('.out').innerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    hideThatKitty = hideThatKitty / $('.this-div-kills-browsers').offset().top
    $('.out')
    .css({"webkit-filter": "blur(4px)",
          "moz-filter":"blur(4px)",
         "ms-filter":"blur(4px)",
         "o-filter":"blur(4px)",
         "filter":"blur(4px)"});
});
```

```css
.out {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background: url(https://placekitten.com/1200/800) no-repeat;
}
.this-div-kills-browsers {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="out">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="this-div-kills-browsers"></div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2dmxLnuy/5/

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. i did not know about the blur filter. But i need to increase and decrease the blur  density with the scroll. :)

Comment: @sam Could "increase and decrease the blur density with the scroll" by adjusting `Npx` value to required `N` during scroll ? Is expected result for "blur" effect to become more pronounced as element scrolls towards top of `window` ?