# Blur section as you scroll down away from it

Tags: jquery, css, blur

I have a series of divs with class '.section'.

I am trying to blur out each div as you scroll down from it and as you scroll up, it looks normal. Even if i know how to do a fade instead then i can figure out the blur.

My problem is getting the blur to happen gradually as you scroll.

Comment: [How to ask a question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating blur effect with css and jQuery on scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414134/creating-blur-effect-with-css-and-jquery-on-scroll)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [offset.top method](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) to calculate absolute distance of element from center point, then normalize that distance to 0-1 percentage range, then apply blur value as max_blur * normalized_distance.

Let's say your center point is at 100px, element at top of the list is at 0px while one at the bottom is at 200px. So absolute distance of both top and bottom is 100px, and absolute distance of center one is 0px. So now calculate blur value:

```
var max_blur = 10; // (px)
var blur =  max_blur * (Math.abs(distance_of_scroll_from_center) / 100)
```

As you can see, elements at top and bottom will have 100% blur while that one in center will have 0%. If we put another element at 50px then it will have 50% of the max blur value and so on.