# Removing blur effect on scroll

Tags: javascript, image, blur

I have photo with blur effect something like this:
filter: blur(6px);
And I'm trying to achieve removing blur effect on scroll. I want the blur to be 0 when I'm scrolling down. The photo is at the bottom of the page so I would prefer not to use the scrollTop function. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Let's see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414134/creating-blur-effect-with-css-and-jquery-on-scroll

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the opposite effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic idea. You are free to adapt the parameters 6 and 50 to your needs :

```
 $(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var pixs = $(document).scrollTop();
  pixs =6-pixs/50;
  if(pixs<0) pixs=0;
  console.log(pixs);
  $(".out").css({"-webkit-filter": "blur("+pixs+"px)","filter":     "blur("+pixs+"px)" })     
 });
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Comment: @ef1eden , could you mark my answer as selected please ?